# Can I use jMonkeyEngine to make a closed source game?

Tags: jmonkeyengine

Can I just share the jMonkeyEngine code and keep my code closed or would I have to make my game open as well? Sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: Please try and do some research on the matter before asking a question like this. Just looking up the definition of "closed source", "commercial" and jMonkeyEngine's license would have cleared things up.

Comment: I did look, and did not find a clear answer. That is why I decided to ask people who might know more about this subject than myself.

Comment: It can get complex.  For instance, just linking to GPL code can sometimes mean that your code must also be under the GPL.  But, sometimes not.  It's not a programming question, but it's valid and not so clear cut.  (Usually API's are under the LGPL to avoid any confusion.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the about page: http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/introduction/

"Free, open-source software (under the New BSD license) – Use our free engine for commercial, educational, or hobby game development"

BSD license allows for closed source commercial development of work based on that software. So yes, your game can be closed source.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure since commercial to me doesn't necessarily mean closed.

Comment: you are correct.  Red Hat is open source software under the GPL and is absolutely commercial.